# What's the meaning of MyEclipse QuickSetup?

Tags: myeclipse

I am using myeclipse now. please select window -> preference->startup and shutdown ,then you will see my options. I want to know what's the meaning of "MyEclipse QuickSetup ", if I don't select this option ,what result will happen ?

Comment: Try it. Let us know. If it an option, it probably wont break anything. Learn through experience.  Make a workspace backup if it helps you sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark, said, try it and see. That's always a good policy for this kind of thing. This particular feature is quite old for MyEclipse, try the latest release, if you can (more features, less bugs). I think it has something to do with updates, so, if you have an old release (6.x?), it's probably safe to disable it.

Comment: As you said, I am using myeclipse 6.5 ,why do you think it   (MyEclipse QuickSetup) has something to do with updates? Do you reference some professional data ?  Would you explain  the meaing of the word "setup" for me ? Becasue my English is so bad . I only can speak Chinese.

Comment: Some problems from the past, on the MyEclipse forums, have shown a stacktrace that has QuickSetup showing in a package that handles updates. I don't know for sure. I would guess it's OK to disable. If you can upgrade to a later release, it won't even be an option.